# Why is this D3 exit() code not working as expected?

Tags: d3.js

Run the code snippet below.

Press "update1" - circles appear.

Press "update2" - there is no apparent change.

On update2 I expected the (top left) black circle to be removed and replaced by a circle at the other end (bottom right) - as the key value returned by the function dataKey is "140:140" for the ammended data and "20:20" for the original data. i.e there is no longer any data item corresponding to "20:20" and there is a new item with key "140:140".

**EDIT**

Since first posting I've noticed that if I replace the objects rather than ammend their properties then things work as expected.. ( use buttons update1B and update2B ).. though this still requires the dataKey function.

```js
let svg = null ;
let space = 20 ;
let dataIndex = 1 ;
let data = [
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"black"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"green"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"blue"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"red"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"yellow"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"purple"}
];

function init(){
    svg = document.getElementById("svg") ;
    svg.setAttribute("height",`${space*dataIndex+10}px`);
    svg.setAttribute("width",`${space*dataIndex+10}px`);     
 }
function dataKey(d){
  // console.log(`${d.x}:${d.y}`);
   return `${d.x}:${d.y}`;
}

function updateData(data){
    
    let d3svg = d3.select(svg);

    let nodes = d3svg.selectAll(".node").data(data,dataKey) ;
    
    nodes
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy",function(d){ return d.y; })
    .attr("r","10px")
    .attr("class","node")
    .attr("fill",function(d){ return d.c; });
    
    nodes.exit().remove();
    
}

function update1(){
    data[0].x = space;
    data[0].y = space;    
    updateData(data) ;
}
function update2(){
    data[0].x = space*dataIndex;
    data[0].y = space*dataIndex;
    updateData(data) ;
}

function update1B(){
    data[0] = {x:space,y:space};   
    updateData(data) ;
}
function update2B(){
    data[0] = {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex};
    updateData(data) ;
}


onload = init ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<button onclick="update1();">update1</button>
<button onclick="update2();">update2</button>
<button onclick="update1B();">update1B</button>
<button onclick="update2B();">update2B</button>
```

Comment: Note that once data is "bound" then the element will point to the same object as your array. So if you change the array you are also changing the data in the element, so there will be no difference to detect!

Comment: @Gordon  I assumed it stored the previous key values in an internal representation somewhere (for comparison) - apparently not....though then why do I need a dataKey function to tell it the item is different (if it is a new object) ? The D3 documentation is a tad nebulous - have to put my waders back on.

Comment: No it stores a reference to the whole object, so that the data can be used to populate attributes and so on. It still needs the key function because the new data may be (should be) new objects so it won't do to just compare object references. The documentation is very precise... it's just a steep learning curve and it takes everyone a while before they get it.

Comment: Yeah, reading https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data at "If a key function is not specified..." ; at the time new data is applied, the old data is still bound to the elements in the selection and, in the presence of a key function, is used for key generation and comparison with the new data and thereby identification of data (and associated elements) as existing,new or removed. Where no key function is present new data is assumed to be/replace old in the order provided (and is associated with existing elements in the same order).

Comment: ..which explains why the updates don't work without the dataKey function - the new objects are taken to be the same data as the old and appear in the update() selection with no effect on the append() or exit() selections where the only processing is taking place (in my code snippet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My confusion lay in how I expected the keys to work ;

I had imagined that an object whose key had changed since the last join would be identified as a new datum.

Crucially, the key value calculated at the time of the join is NOT stored for comparison in subsequent joins ;

The key value calculated at the time of the join is NOT stored/available for comparison in subsequent joins and hence won't identify the same object as a new or removed datum.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding update1 / update2 -- the data is bound by index (if no key is specified), and since the length of data array didn't decrease, the exit selection is empty (and as a matter of fact, the enter selection when updating should be empty as well, since the data length didn't increase either). Instead, your existing elements got their data changed, however you do not react to it at all (i.e. you do something with `nodes.enter()`, something with `nodes.exit()`, but nothing with just the `nodes`).

Generally, you'll want to only use `append` and `style` (and optionally, if you use transitions, starting values for other attributes) for the `enter` selection, and then merge it with the update selection, before updating the attributes for the new data.

Here is your code, with the `updateData` function fixed

```js
let svg = null ;
let space = 20 ;
let dataIndex = 1 ;
let data = [
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"black"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"green"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"blue"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"red"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"yellow"},
    {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex++,c:"purple"}
];

function init(){
    svg = document.getElementById("svg") ;
    svg.setAttribute("height",`${space*dataIndex+10}px`);
    svg.setAttribute("width",`${space*dataIndex+10}px`);     
 }
function dataKey(d){
  // console.log(`${d.x}:${d.y}`);
   return `${d.x}:${d.y}`;
}

function updateData(data){
    
    let d3svg = d3.select(svg);

    let nodes = d3svg.selectAll(".node").data(data,dataKey) ;
    
    nodes
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class","node")
    .merge(nodes)
    .attr("cx",function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy",function(d){ return d.y; })
    .attr("r","10px")
    .attr("fill",function(d){ return d.c; });
    
    nodes.exit().remove();
    
}

function update1(){
    data[0].x = space;
    data[0].y = space;    
    updateData(data) ;
}
function update2(){
    data[0].x = space*dataIndex;
    data[0].y = space*dataIndex;
    updateData(data) ;
}

function update1B(){
    data[0] = {x:space,y:space};   
    updateData(data) ;
}
function update2B(){
    data[0] = {x:space*dataIndex,y:space*dataIndex};
    updateData(data) ;
}


onload = init ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<button onclick="update1();">update1</button>
<button onclick="update2();">update2</button>
<button onclick="update1B();">update1B</button>
<button onclick="update2B();">update2B</button>
```

Comment: Sorry Coderino but your answer relates to "if no key is specified" when in all cases a key is specified - and this was what was confusing me ; why the key was not working to identify new/removed objects.